# How to solve $ \frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{c}{x}-2\log \left( \frac{1+x}{x}\right)+A=0$

Tags: nonlinear-system, approximation-theory

How to find a solution to the following equation
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{c}{x}-2\log \left( \frac{1+x}{x}\right)+A=0
\end{align*}

where $c$ and $A$ are some constants such that $c\ge 1$ and $A>0$.

I tried a few softwares to solve it but I don't think there is an analytic solution.

Could some one please suggest a way to find solution in some approximate sense?
Thank you

Comment: It is a concave function, so an effective numerical method is Newton's method.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Would it always converge?

Comment: given a starting point sufficiently close to the solution, yes. You may take a good starting point by considering a polynomial approximation of $\log(x+1)-\log(x)=\int_{x}^{x+1}\frac{dt}{t}$.

Comment: If it is a concave function on an interval, then it may be shown that newton's method will always converge to the extrema. The issue here is that c and A are parameters, so it's better to specify them before performing the numerical technique.

Answer (score 0):

Rearranging, probably useless but I'll leave it here:

$$2\log \left(\frac{1+x}{x}\right) = \frac{x}{x^2+x} - \frac{cx + c}{x^2+x} + \frac{Ax^2 + Ax}{x^2 + x} $$

$$\log \left(\frac{1+x}{x}\right) = \frac{Ax^2 + (A+1-c)x - c}{2x^2 + 2x}$$

$$\frac{1+x}{x} = \exp\left(\frac{Ax^2 + (A+1-c)x - c}{2x^2 + 2x}\right)$$